# Set length of a printing document in CSS

Tags: css, printing, alignment, thermal-printer

I'm printing barcodes using a thermal printer. The size of each sticker on roll is (width: 3inch, height: 1.5inch). everything is working fine but the problem is I'm getting 3 or 4 blank stickers before the printed one. how can I set the length i.e 1.5 inches for one printout. I used the CSS property

`@media print{
@page{ size: 3in 1.5in; }
}`

but it printed the barcode vertically after adding this CSS.
I just want my printer to stop after printing 1 sticker. I don't want it to give blank stickers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar problem. I had "Zebra" thermal printer and "Subiekt GT" software (it had module for designing labels with barcodes).
It kept printing additional empty labels until I fixed settings on my printer and software (page sizes / label sizes / margins/ unprintable area), try experimenting with these.
It's also possible that it is hardware fault/driver fault.
You can also try calibrating your thermal printer.